# codeigniter xss validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

In CI [userguide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html) it says "The following is a list of all the prepping functions that are available to use:"

**xss_clean** = *Runs the data through the XSS filtering function.....*

Comments in my code has my question. Please read.

Note: Not interested enabling xss globally!!!

Thanks in advance

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('select_language', 'Language', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

//Has this been cleaned above while validating and ready to be used or ...
$language = $this->input->post('text_fullname');

//... do I have to add true to run the data through the XSS filtering again myslef?
$language = $this->input->post('text_fullname', true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post data won't be filtered until you actually run the form validation.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
    'select_language',
    'Language',
    'trim|required|xss_clean'
);

// Unaltered $_POST input
$this->input->post('select_language');

$this->form_validation->run();

// Trimmed and xss_cleaned
$this->input->post('select_language');
```

Aside: In my opinion, xss filtering makes more sense to use where it actually matters, on *output*, not input. For example, if the xss filter is improved in a future release, you would want to take advantage of it right? If you filter input only, it would be impossible without running the xss_clean function *again* on your output, which defeats the purpose of using it as a form validation rule.

Comment: After `$this->form_validation->run();`, I can go ahead and use `$language = $this->input->post('text_fullname');` without XSS filtering second time. Do I get it right?

Comment: Correct, the "prepping" functions or "filters" won't be applied until after the form validation runs, and they write the new values directly to `$_POST`.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're doing here, but I question the need for an `xss_clean` form validation rule at all. Might be a good idea for you to look up what XSS actually is and think about how it's actually used.

Comment: If the downvote is about my "aside", I'd like to hear why so I can enlighten you. Please, speak up!

Comment: I up voted. I don't know if someone down voted though. Also I accepted your answer. Can we not see who up votes or down votes? If not possibles, at least those who have plenty of reputation like you, should be allowed to see.

Comment: There is one anonymous downvote, I assume they are misguided about what XSS is and does. The above comment was directed toward them, an invitation for discussion. It could be about something else though, maybe they just think the answer is wrong or don't like my avatar.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the help. It will help me stop using XSS twice.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer suggest you need to run the form validation first, but!

Your `$this->input->post('text_fullname')` wont be cleaned because you have set a validation rule for `select_language` and not `text_fullname`