# xss filtering for callback functions

Tags: php, codeigniter

As far as learned from [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765675/codeigniter-xss-validation/13766074#13766074), `xss_clean` will filter `$this->input->post('text_url')` after calling `$this->form_validation->run()`. The question is will it also filter `$this->input->post('textarea_content')` in callback function?

Thanks

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('text_url', 'Website link', 'trim|xss_clean|callback_minimum_fields[' . $this->input->post('textarea_content') . ']');

$this->form_validation->run();

//Filtered
$text_url = $this->input->post('text_url');

//Filtered as well?
$textarea_content = $this->input->post('textarea_content');
```

**CALLBACK**

```
public function minimum_fields($url, $content)
{
    if ($url == '' && $content == '')
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('minimum_fields', 'Please provide info for at least one of these: "Website link" and "Content".');
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: In this case, would `xss_clean` cover data [textarea_content] in callback or it only applies to [text_url]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Filtered as well?
$textarea_content = $this->input->post('textarea_content');
```

No, you didn't set a "prepping" rule in your form validation. In fact, you haven't validated the `textarea_content` field at all.

Besides that, you haven't run the form validation at the time you set the rules, so passing any POST data into a callback function will be the original data.

Passing post data like that into a callback here, where the rules are just strings, is very dangerous and likely to break your script. Consider:

```
$_POST['textarea_content'] = ']|var_dump|exit|some_nonsense[';

$this->form_validation->set_rules(
    'text_url',
    'Website link',
    'callback_minimum_fields[' . $this->input->post('textarea_content') . ']'
);

// Produces this rule:
// callback_minimum_fields[]|var_dump|exit|some_nonsense[]
```

Those "rules" would be injected into your form validation rules, since in this context, it's just a string. It might be better to have your callback read the postdata directly or to take another approach, but this is very unsafe. Even if you xss_clean it first, it doesn't matter.

Once again, I urge you to spend more time understanding what XSS is and then decide if it makes any sense to worry about in this situation. XSS only occurs on *output*.

Comment: This part is good to know: "It might be better to have your callback read the postdata directly or to take another approach, but this is very unsafe.". How do I do it though? Is there any example you can share via url? Thanks

Comment: if you are sending other values what about the same field value which callback function is getting called, how will you write callback function for handling two arguments

Comment: @MadMax: I can't really say without seeing the callback function itself.

Comment: @PankajKhairnar: Due to limitations with CI, you can't normally have a callback with more than one argument.

Comment: and then how you are passing value to it, and giving downvote to me

Comment: @Wesley - I added callback above.

Comment: @WesleyMurch : it was my bad I tested it is working fine +1 for good answer.

Answer (score 0):

So of course the obvious thing would be to pick a field, make it required, and then put required in the validation. But if what you are saying is - one OR the other of these fields are required - you might as well just do that as a separate check after field validation.

AND this makes sense from a usability point of view - normal validation takes place PER FIELD. the error message is tied to the field. if you have a requirement that concerns more then one field - then that message should appear separately.

AND here is simple CI tip for XSS clean, just use TRUE like:

```
// adding TRUE means we are filtered
$text_url = $this->input->post('text_url', TRUE);
$textarea_content = $this->input->post('textarea_content', TRUE);

 // check if both fields came back blank
if( $text_url == '' && $textarea_content == '' ) 
{
// validation failed, show the form again, make your own message to pass to view
}
else
{
// its all good
}
```